# delphi generics with constructor constraint

Tags: generics, delphi-xe7

I try compile this code:

```
TMyClass<T: class, constructor> = class(TObjectList<T>)
public
  constructor Create; reintroduce;
end;
TConcretClass = class(TMyClass<TConcretClass>)
public
  constructor Create; reintroduce;
end;
```

But I get next error:

```
E2513 Type parameter 'T' must have one public parameterless constructor named Create
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TConcretClass = class(TMyClass<TConcretClass>)
```

I don't think you mean for the class you are declaring to be a list containing members whose type are itself. In any case, the compiler is objecting because `TObjectList<T>` has a constructor with parameters that cannot be hidden. The compiler says:

> E2513 Type parameter 'T' must have one public parameterless constructor named Create

And `TObjectList<T>` cannot meet that requirement.

I suspect you want something more like this:

```
type
  TMyClass<T: class, constructor> = class(TObjectList<T>)
  end;

  TListMemberClass = class(TObject)
  end;

  TConcreteClass = class(TMyClass<TListMemberClass>)
  end;
```

Comment: OK. I've explained why the compiler reports that error, as you asked. Do you understand why it does so?

Comment: Ok, Why don't compile this code:

    TNode<T: class, constructor> = class
    public
      constructor Create;
    end;
  
    TConcretNode = class(TNode<TConcretNode>)
    public
      constructor Create;
    end;

 TConcretNode have only one public parameterless constructor named Create

Comment: In that case the definition of `TConcretNode` is not complete, and the compiler does not know that `TConcretNode` has the necessary qualities.

Comment: Do you need any more help with the question that you asked?